# Возможно ли подключить дебаг frontend'а к Intellij Idea?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, intellij-idea, frontend

К примеру я разрабатываю продукт на angular 1. Есть ли возможность, чтобы не открывать "инструменты разработчика" в браузере, а непосредственно в Idea ловить точки остановки?

Comment: в webstorm есть все необходимые плагины(расширение для браузера надо, но он предложит его установить), однако страницы по 100000 строк жуёт хуже чем отладчик в хроме...

Comment: @StrangerintheQ спасибо за подсказку)